# urllib.urlopen not returning response body

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I'm trying to download JSON from a url as a string and parse it. This is the code I'm using:

```
json_data = urllib.urlopen('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').read()
parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)
```

It current outputs `<Response 27943 bytes [200 OK]>`. Ok so its a response object or the string representation of a response? How do I access the response body?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're seeing `<Response 27943 bytes [200 OK]>`. When I execute that, `parsed_data` is a list containing 100 elements. Each of these is a dictionary with the keys `'body', 'userId', 'id', 'title'`.

```
>>> type(parsed_data)
<type 'list'>
>>> len(parsed_data)
100
>>> parsed_data[0].keys()
[u'body', u'userId', u'id', u'title']
```

So to get the *body* of each, you could do:

```
for item in parsed_data:
    print item['body']
    # or do
    print item['title'], item['body']  # just an example using print
```